# Django Register View not Saving User Model to Database

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-registration

I built a registration form + view + template, but when I try to register, the user is not being saved to the database, neither does it log me in.

I expected my form to register my user and save it to the database.
This is my code

(Register form)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def check_password(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match!')
        return self.cleaned_data['password2']
```

(Register view)

```
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            user = register_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password = register_form.cleaned_data['password']
            # Automatically log in the user after registration
            username = register_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = register_form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                # Redirect to a success page or home page
                return redirect('home1:index')  # Adjust 'home' to your home page URL name
    else:
        register_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'register_form': register_form})
```

(Register Template)

```
<form class="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label class="label" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <label class="label" for="username">Username:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <label class="label" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <label class="label" for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input class="input" type="password" id="confirm_password" name="password1">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form is not registering user because register_form.is_valid() is giving false.

Root cause: form does not contain field password2.

to fix this error change your html like this:

```
<form class="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label class="label" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <label class="label" for="username">Username:</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <label class="label" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <label class="label" for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input class="input" type="password" id="confirm_password" name="password2">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

---

To identify these kinds of issues you should always check `register_form.errors`

You can also print errors on html like this:

```
{{register_form.errors}}
```